# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'onnxruntime'

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, neural-network, kaggle

I'm taking a Microsoft PyTorch course and trying to implement on Kaggle Notebooks but I kept having the same error message over and over again: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'onnxruntime'". I've checked everywhere possible if I could find a solution to it but none, I even tried installing it manually using pip in the notebook, but it's still not working. I've checked the official onnxruntime website and documentation but there's nowhere it states anything about something being outdated or any other issue. Someone help. My code won't run because it says "onnxruntime is not defined". Here are my imports:

```
    %matplotlib inline
import torch
import onnxruntime
from torch import nn
import torch.onnx as onnx
import torchvision.models as models
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
```

and the code cell I'm trying to run

```
session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(onnx_model, None)
input_name = session.get_inputs()[0].name
output_name = session.get_outputs()[0].name

result = session.run([output_name], {input_name: x.numpy()})
predicted, actual = classes[result[0][0].argmax(0)], classes[y]
print(f'Predicted: "{predicted}", Actual: "{actual}"')
```

And you can find the complete notebook here: https://www.kaggle.com/faisalalbasu/complete-model

Answer (score 2):

- the error occurs because "import" cannot find onnxruntime in any of the **paths**, check where import is searching and see if onnxruntime is in there.
- check what path pip install installs to, that way in the future you won't have the same problem! :)